# How do I render a navigation menu like my theme does?

Tags: menus, page-template

I am using the theme [suffusion](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/suffusion), and I'm trying to add a custom navigation menu to only one of my pages.
I've managed to get it almost working using this in my page template:

```
if(is_page('123')
{
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'my-menu' ) );
}
```

Where `'123'` is the page id of the page that I want, and `'my-menu'` is the menu I want. The page is using the correct template. The correct items are generated with appropriate links, but they are rendered as an unordered list like so:

> - Item 1
> - Item 2
> - Item 3
> - Item 4

If I have the menu bar rendered by my theme (by placing it in one of the slots in the dashboard), it renders this menu horizontally as attractive-looking buttons.

When I do it this way, it correctly only shows up on the page that I want, but is rendered as a vertical bulletted list.

What do I need to change so that the menu is rendered as if done by the theme?

Answer (score 1):

Your theme's CSS stylesheet is controlling the appearance of the menu, and targeting it via the div that contains it:

```
#head-nav ul li
```

Your menu either has to appear within the same markup, or your CSS styles need to be appended / modified to target your new menu.